# nodejs get value in object where keys are a list of words to match with a sentence

Tags: node.js, string

so i have an object where keys are a list of words and the values are functions that look like this :

```
{
  'test,qwe,asdwe': [Function: test1],
  'lol,xd': [Function: test2]
}
```

I have a sentence and i want to match it with a key where ANY word in the sentence match any word in the keys (a key cannot have 2 times the same word)

Example with the object upper :

A sentence  `"hi , how are you lol"` match with the second function `test2`

I can match the keys with

```
Object.keys(myObject).some(key => key === 'lol')
```

but it doesn't work if the sentence has 'lol hhh' , it must match with only 'lol' in the sentence , i think i can do it with a strstr maybe ? but i don't know what is the best way .

if someone can help me please =)

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do with the match if one is found, can you give an example of what would happen?

Comment: if it match i want to get the function to then execute it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first transform the object into another one whose keys are all single words (eg, separate out `'lol,xd'` into two separate key-value pairs). Then you can construct a regular expression by alternating between all keys of the object, then match the string against the regex and call the appropriate function:

```js
const initialObj = {
  'test,qwe,asdwe': () => console.log('test1'),
  'lol,xd': () => console.log('test2'),
};
const separatedObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(initialObj).flatMap(
    ([key, fn]) => key.split(',').map(word => [word, fn])
  )
);

const regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(separatedObj).join('|'), 'g');
for (const word of "hi , how are you lol".match(regex)) {
  separatedObj[word]();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it shorter ? or not with regex ? regex isnt a bit heavy for just this ? Thank for your answer tho

Comment: String matching against different possible patterns is *exactly* the sort of thing regular expressions excel at, often far beyond other more programmatic solutions. I guess if you really really wanted to you could iterate over every index of the string, slice it, then iterate over each possible key and check if the sliced string `startsWith` the key - but that's so much longer and uglier. A regex is really a much better approach here.